# Get a file knowing the name and possible extensions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a school project. I'm creating a webform that helps the user to edit some entries of a database (let's say I want to edit an entry of the 'books' table).

First, I display a list of books, the user can click on the one he/she wants to edit and all the informations will be retrieved and displayed inside input forms, so that he/she can edit and then submit the updated data.

I'm having one problem. Associated with each book there's a picture that I'd like to display, unfortunately all I can retrieve from the database is the name of the picture file but not the extension. The only extensions allowed are jpeg, gif, jpg and png. What I tried this far is the following function:

```
function UrlExists(url)
    {   
        var ext = [ ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".gif" ];
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url_ext = '';

        $.each(ext, function(key, value){
                        http.open('HEAD', url+value, false);
                        http.send();
                        if(http.status!=404){
                            url_ext = url+value;
                        }

                    });
        if(url_ext){
            return url_ext;
        }else{
            return "image_path/notfound.jpg";
        }


    }
```

It's not pretty but it works. The only side-problem are all the warnings on the dev-tool in chrome. I don't really mind but I feel like this is bad practice, I'm basically trying to retrieve the file hitting the server with every allowed extension.

This code works because there are no files with the same name, so there cannot be "picture.jpg" AND "picture.png". Is there a good solution to this problem ? I tried using some php inside jquery, with the glob() function, but I couldn't make it work. Something like this:

```
$('#image_id').attr('src', '<?php echo json_encode(glob("image_path/filename.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)) ?>' );
```

It's not really doing any php work, I think I'm missing something to make php work inside a jQuery function or maybe it runs when the document is loaded so it wouldn't work. Anyway I'm not even sure this can work. Any help would be much appreciated. Keep in mind I'm no php/jquery expert ;)

Comment: do the images have the extension in DB?

Comment: What I would do in this case is make some `get_image.php` script which searches disk for the file and actually returns it dynamically.  In your HTML, you could always use `<img src="get_image.php?id=12344" />`, and then your PHP script returns the actual image for the book.

Comment: Unfortunately no, they didn't think about keeping a field for the image extension, only the file name is saved. So if a file is called "picture.png", there's a row in the images table with fields : img_id, img_path, img_name. None of them has the extension only the full path or just the file name.

Comment: @Brad that's intereseting, I didn't think it would be this simple to link a php script to the image src attribute. Can you just explain why there's a "...?id=12344", what's that for ?

Comment: @G4bri3l I think you're not understanding what I'm suggesting.  You have regular HTML, but the PHP script instead of returning HTML literally returns the binary image data through `readfile()` or similar.  Also don't forget to set the appropriate `Content-Type` header.  The ID is so that the PHP script can look up the book in the database to get the name, and then search disk for the image name related to it.

Comment: @Brad oh ok, got it! I'll give it a try. I thought you were returning the path not the actual binary image. Thanks ;)

Comment: I changed it a bit but I ended up using a php script as you suggested ;) ..just out of curiosity, does it make any difference if I use the readfile method or if I just echo the full path ?